# how to set default constraint to UTC time with TimeZone in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, default-constraint

I have to add default value to a datetime column with UTC time with Timezone, right now I am using the `GETUTCDATE()` in default constraint, but it is not adding the timezone information to the column.

Please help me.

Comment: do you want server timezone?

Comment: [`SYSDATETIMEOFFSET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: `datetime` doesn't include any timezone information. You're using the wrong method, probably the wrong type too. Use `datetimeoffset` and [SYSDATETIMEOFFSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead.

Comment: If every single value in the column is going to be UTC (i.e. no other offset will ever need to be supported or allowed), consider using a `DATETIME2` (with a default of `SYSUTCDATETIME()`) and converting it to a `DATETIMEOFFSET` only when necessary, as the storage for the offset is otherwise pretty much wasted. Of course, this does require that clients adhere to the same discipline (whether themselves or by passing through a stored procedure), otherwise you can end up with surprise unconverted local times, which can be really hard to detect and recover from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type that includes timezone information (specifically, the offset) is [datetimeoffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.8). [GETUTCDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getutcdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) returns a plain old `DATETIME` which has no timezone indication, not even a Local vs UTC indicator.

If you care about timezones and offsets, use a `datetimeoffset` column and ` [SYSDATETIMEOFFSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as its default

Comment: But i want to store UTC time.

Comment: @RamSingh Then by definition there is no timezone offset.

Comment: @RamSingh there's no "UTC" time. `datetime` has *no* UTC/non-UTC indicator. It's just a datetime value whose interpretation is up to the application. Without `datetimeoffset` you'll have to ensure that all applications, all client code works with UTC

Comment: @RamSingh on the other hand, with `datetimeoffset` you don't really care about UTC as the values are comparable even if they are stored with different offsets. You can switch the value to UTC, ie `+00:00` if you want for display purposes but that doesn't affect sorting, searching and comparisons

Answer (score 1):

You need the `DATETIMEOFFSET` data type and the `SWITCHOFFSET` function

```
DECLARE @t TABLE 
(
 id INT,
 dt DATETIMEOFFSET DEFAULT (SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),'+00:00'))
);

INSERT @t(id) VALUES(1);

SELECT id, dt, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() 
FROM @t;
```

Since 2016 you can use AT TIME ZONE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017